# Inform right-hand side of pipeline of left-side failure?

Tags: bash, pipe, pipeline

I've grown fond of using a generator-like pattern between functions in my shell scripts. Something like this:

```
parse_commands /da/cmd/file | process_commands
```

However, the basic problem with this pattern is that if parse_command encounters an error, the only way I have found to notify process_command that it failed is by explicitly telling it (e.g. echo "FILE_NOT_FOUND"). This means that every potentially faulting operation in parse_command would have to be fenced.

Is there no way process_command can detect that the left side exited with a non-zero exit code?

Comment: As always, second googling found this http://www.unix.com/302268337-post4.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698407/kill-next-command-in-pipeline-on-failure-bash/32699218#32699218 is a somewhat clearer version of this question which has, arguably, better answers (the question asks how to inform the right-hand side of the pipeline of the failure, but the accepted answer only addresses how to detect the situation in the parent shell).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does the pipe process continue even if the first process has ended, or is the issue that you have no way of knowing that the first process failed?

If it's the latter, you can look at the `PIPESTATUS` variable (which is actually a BASH array). That will give you the exit code of the first command:

```
parse_commands /da/cmd/file | process_commands
temp=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
if [ ${temp[0]} -ne 0 ]
then
    echo 'parse_commands failed'
elif [ ${temp[1]} -ne 0 ]
then
    echo 'parse_commands worked, but process_commands failed'
fi
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use co-processes.

Comment: It's true this supplies the information, but it cannot be done inside process_command, so readability suffers.

Answer (score 29):

Use `set -o pipefail` on top of your bash script so that when the left side of the pipe fails (exit status != 0), the right side does not execute.

Comment: "set -o pipefail" do not prevent the right side to be executed, so it doesn't answer to the initial question that was "how to notify the right side..." Basically this change the exit status of the pipe: by default the exit status of the pipe is the exit status of the right side, with this option it's the max of piped commands.

Comment: @dtracers Yes, the purpose is exactly to make it look like the entire command failed, if at least one of the stages fails. I'm still wondering what's the difference between `shopt` options and `set` ones. Oh well.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike the and operator (&&), the pipe operator (|) works by spawning both processes simultaneously, so the first process can pipe its output to the second process without the need of buffering the intermediate data. This allows for processing of large amounts of data with little memory or disk usage.

Therefore, the exit status of the first process wouldn't be available to the second one until it's finished.

Comment: Not necessarily true. See, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32699218/14122

Comment: @Charles well still I'd say that you can only get the exit status of the first process once it has exited. But indeed according to the various answers, including yours, using FIFOs or PIPESTATUS sounds like a versatile solution for the OP question allowing to access the exit status in an adequate way.

Answer (score 4):

You could try some work arround using a fifo:

```
mkfifo /tmp/a
cat /tmp/a | process_commands &

parse_cmd /da/cmd/file > /tmp/a || (echo "error"; # kill process_commands)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is about the best you can do without writing a C program that does roughly the same thing, only with a regular pipe rather than a named pipe.  I wonder of the zsh coproc facility would help with this, but I don't really know much about it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6566171/1608986) was missing a closing `}` on line 5.

After fixing this, the code will throw a `-ne: unary operator expected` error, which points to a problem: `PIPESTATUS` is overwritten by the conditional following the `if` command, so the return value of `process_commands` will never be checked!

This is because `[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]` is [equivalent to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586252/1608986) `test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0`, which changes `$PIPESTATUS` just like any other command. For example:

```
return0 () { return 0;}
return3 () { return 3;}

return0 | return3
echo "PIPESTATUS: ${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

This returns `PIPESTATUS: 0 3` as expected. But what if we introduce conditionals?

```
return0 | return3
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1st command error: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
elif [ ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "2nd command error: ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
else
    echo "PIPESTATUS: ${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
    echo "Both return codes = 0."
fi
```

We get the `[: -ne: unary operator expected` error, and this:

```
PIPESTATUS: 2
Both return codes = 0.
```

To fix this, `$PIPESTATUS` should be stored in a different array variable, like so:

```
return0 | return3
TEMP=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
echo "TEMP: ${TEMP[@]}"
if [ ${TEMP[0]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1st command error: ${TEMP[0]}"
elif [ ${TEMP[1]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "2nd command error: ${TEMP[1]}"
else
    echo "TEMP: ${TEMP[@]}"
    echo "All return codes = 0."
fi
```

Which prints:

```
TEMP: 0 3
2nd command error: 3
```

as intended.

Edit: I fixed the accepted answer, but I'm leaving this explanation for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `command1 && command2` then command2 will only be executed when the first command is successful - otherwise boolean short-circuiting kicks in.  One way of using this would be to build a first command (your `parse_commands...`) that dumps to a temporary and then have the second command take from that file.

Edit: By judicious use of `;` you can tidy up the temporary file, e.g.

```
(command1 && command2) ; rm temporaryfile
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in bash 4.0, which adds the `coproc` builtin from ash.  This coprocess facility is borrowed from ksh, which uses a different syntax.  The only shell I have access to on my system that supports coprocesses is ksh.  Here is a solution written with ksh:

```
parse_commands  /da/cmd/file |&
parser=$!

process_commands <&p &
processor=$!

if wait $parser
then
    wait $processor
    exit $?
else
    kill $processor
    exit 1
fi
```

The idea is to start `parse_commands` in the background with pipes connecting it to the main shell.  The pid is saved in `parser`.  Then `process_commands` is started with the output of `parse_commands` as its input.  (That is what `<&p` does.)  This is also put in the background with its pid saved in `processor`.

With both of those in the background connected by a pipe, our main shell is free to wait for the parser to terminate.  If it terminates without an error, we wait for the processor to finish and exit with its return code.  If it terminates *with* an error, we kill the processor and exit with non-zero status.

It should be fairly straightforward to translate this to use the bash 4.0 / ash `coproc` builtin, but I don't have good documentation, nor a way to test that.

Comment: How do you ensure that `process_commands` doesn't exit from hitting EOF (when the write end of the FIFO is closed) before getting signaled?

Answer (score 0):

You may run `parse_commands /da/cmd/file` in an explicit subshell and `echo` the exit status of this subshell through the pipe to `process_commands` which is also run in an explicit subshell to process the piped data contained in `/dev/stdin`.

Far from being elegant, but seems to get the job done :)

A simple example:

```
(
( ls -l ~/.bashrcxyz; echo $? ) | 
( 
piped="$(</dev/stdin)"; 
[[ "$(tail -n 1 <<<"$piped")" -eq 0 ]] && printf '%s\n' "$piped" | sed '$d' || exit 77 
); 
echo $?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
parse_commands /da/cmd/file > >(process_commands)
```

Comment: Not here. Test with `false > >(/bin/echo foo)`