# I encountered "unary operator expected" in a Bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement, unary-operator

In my Bash script, I have a function to return 0 or 1 (true or false) for the later *main* function's condition.

```
function1 () {
    if [[ "${1}" =~ "^ ...some regexp... $" ]] ; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Then in my *main* function:

```
main () {
    for arg in ${@} ; do
        if [ function1 ${arg} ] ; then
            ...
        elif [ ... ] ; then
            ...
        fi
    done
}
```

However, when I ran this script it always gave me an error message:

> [: function1: unary operator expected

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that, at least in bash version 4, you should not quote the regular expression: doing so forces simple string matching -- [documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57). Also, you should use `for arg in "$@"` with the quotes, or simpler `for arg; do ...`

Comment: You should put your regex in a variable. `pattern='^ ...some regexp... $'; if [[ $1 =~ $pattern ]]`. Note that inside double square brackets, it's not necessary to quote variables and as glenn said, the regex (variable) should never be quoted.

Comment: The canonical may be *["unary operator expected" error in Bash if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/)*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are making the common mistake of assuming that `[` is part of the `if` command's syntax.  It is not; the syntax of `if` is simply

```
if command; then
    ... things which should happen if command's result code was 0
else
    ... things which should happen otherwise
fi
```

One of the common `command`s we use is `[` which is an alias for the command `test`.  It is a simple command for comparing strings, numbers, and files.  It accepts a fairly narrow combination of arguments, and tends to generate confusing and misleading error messages if you don't pass it the expected arguments.  (Or rather, the error messages are adequate and helpful once you get used to it, but they are easily misunderstood if you're not used.)

In your `main` function, the call to `[` appears misplaced.  You probably mean

```
if function "$arg"; then
    ...
elif ... ; then ...
```

By the way, for good measure, you should also always quote your strings.  Use `"$1"` not `$1`, and `"$arg"` instead of `$arg`.

The historical reasons for `test` as a general kitchen sink of stuff the authors didn't want to make part of the syntax of `if` is one of the less attractive designs of the original Bourne shell.  Bash and `zsh` offer alternatives which are less unwieldy (like the `[[` double brackets in bash, which you use in your `function1` definition), and of course, POSIX `test` is a lot more well-tempered than the original creation from Bell Labs.

As an additional clarification, your function can be simplified to just

```
function1 () {
    ! [[ "$1" =~ "^ ...some regexp... $" ]]
}
```

That is, perform the test with `[[` and reverse its result code.  (The "normal" case would be to return 0 for success, but maybe you are attempting to verify that the string doesn't match?)

Comment: those ... represent script after ${1}, and in my actual script i carefully split my script and brackets with one space. so i don't think it is the problem with that

Comment: no, my function 1 actually checks if that $1 is matching some kind of regular expression. and my function 1 just works fine standing alone. so what i think is that there is some problem with the condition in my main function

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed the error in `main`.   Thanks for the hint.  The basic analysis still holds; `[` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks! i shouldn't use the brackets within my conditions of main. thanks!

Comment: I repurposed this answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36371520/874188 which is a more focused question. If you were linked here, perhaps click through to the newer question.