# sourceing a setup.sh gives bash error /tmp/setup.sh.DPE4BtgiZY: cannot overwrite existing file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ros

I am trying to install the latest [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation) Hydro, everything went one fine as everything seemed to be downloaded and configured to its proper places. I am supposes source a setup script every time I use ros. The problem occurred when I tried:

```
source setup.sh
```

a error occurs :

```
bash: /tmp/setup.sh.DPE4BtgiZY: cannot overwrite existing file
bash: [: 0: unary operator expected
```

I have tried running the script as root or making it a executable ,but none works and the same error persists.  below is the setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# generated from catkin/cmake/template/setup.sh.in

# Sets various environment variables and sources additional environment hooks.
# It tries it's best to undo changes from a previously sourced setup file before.
# Supported command line options:
# --extend: skips the undoing of changes from a previously sourced setup file

# since this file is sourced either use the provided _CATKIN_SETUP_DIR
# or fall back to the destination set at configure time
: ${_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR:=/opt/ros/hydro}
_SETUP_UTIL="$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/_setup_util.py"
unset _CATKIN_SETUP_DIR

if [ ! -f "$_SETUP_UTIL" ]; then
  echo "Missing Python script: $_SETUP_UTIL"
  return 22
fi

# detect if running on Darwin platform
_UNAME=`uname -s`
_IS_DARWIN=0
if [ "$_UNAME" = "Darwin" ]; then
  _IS_DARWIN=1
fi
unset _UNAME

# make sure to export all environment variables
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
export CPATH
if [ $_IS_DARWIN -eq 0 ]; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
  export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
unset _IS_DARWIN
export PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export PYTHONPATH


# remember type of shell if not already set
if [ -z "$CATKIN_SHELL" ]; then
  CATKIN_SHELL=sh
fi

# invoke Python script to generate necessary exports of environment variables
_SETUP_TMP=`mktemp /tmp/setup.sh.XXXXXXXXXX`
if [ $? -ne 0 -o ! -f "$_SETUP_TMP" ]; then
  echo "Could not create temporary file: $_SETUP_TMP"
  return 1
fi
CATKIN_SHELL=$CATKIN_SHELL "$_SETUP_UTIL" $@ > $_SETUP_TMP
unset _SETUP_UTIL
. $_SETUP_TMP
rm -f $_SETUP_TMP
unset _SETUP_TMP

# source all environment hooks
_i=0
while [ $_i -lt $_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_COUNT ]; do
  eval _envfile=\$_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_$_i
  unset _CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_$_i
  eval _envfile_workspace=\$_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_${_i}_WORKSPACE
  unset _CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_${_i}_WORKSPACE
  # set workspace for environment hook
  CATKIN_ENV_HOOK_WORKSPACE=$_envfile_workspace
  . "$_envfile"
  unset CATKIN_ENV_HOOK_WORKSPACE
  _i=$((_i + 1))
done
unset _i

unset _CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_COUNT
```

Comment: clean up /tmp/setup.* and run again

Comment: @michael I have tried that already , there isn't a file like that in `./tmp/`. I tried emptying the whole `./tmp` dir but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two modifications to setup.sh to get it working:

Under *"Invoke Python script to generate necessary exports of environment variables"* change

```
CATKIN_SHELL=$CATKIN_SHELL "$_SETUP_UTIL" $@ > $_SETUP_TMP
```

to

```
CATKIN_SHELL=$CATKIN_SHELL "$_SETUP_UTIL" $@ >> $_SETUP_TMP
```

Under *"source all environment hooks"* change the termination condition of the while block from

```
while [ $_i -lt $_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_COUNT ]; do
```

to

```
while [[ $_i -lt $_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_COUNT ]]; do
```

The errors should disappear.

References:

- [cannot overwrite existing file](http://forum.ivorde.ro/bash-bash-output-cannot-overwrite-existing-file-t882.html)
- [unary operator expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/unary-operator-expected)