# Why does my Bash script generate a "unary operator expected error"?

Tags: bash

I trying to make a program that outputs a triangle of stars in Bash.

Here is what it would look like:

[image]

However, I am getting:

> line 8: [: 1: unary operator expected error

Here is my code

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p "Please input a number for a magical surprise diagram: " input

tri1="1"
tri2="1"

while [ $tri1 -le $input ]; do
    while [ $tri2 -le $tri1 ]; do
        echo -n "*"
        tri2=$( ( $tri2 + 1 ) )
    done

    echo -n ""
    tri1=$( ( $tri1 + 1 ) )
    tri2=1
done
```

I am a beginner at Bash scripting, so please bear with me as I learn.

Comment: The canonical may be *["unary operator expected" error in Bash if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p "Plese input a number for a magical surprise diagram : " input

tri1="1"
tri2="1"

while [ $tri1 -le $input ]; do
   while [ $tri2 -le $tri1 ]; do
   echo -n "*"
   ((tri2=$tri2 + 1 ))    #fixed
   done
  echo -n "" 
    ((tri1= $tri1 + 1 )) #fixed
    tri2=1
  echo ""      # need add a return, otherwise, all output in one line.
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! I didn't realize about the last echo line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a revised version that takes full advantage of arithmetic evaluation - `((...))` - and expansion `$((...))`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Please input a number for a magical surprise diagram: " input

tri1=1
tri2=1

while (( tri1 <= input )); do
  while (( tri2 <= tri1 )); do
    printf '*'
    (( ++tri2 ))
  done
  printf '\n'
  (( ++tri1 ))
  tri2=1
done
```

Also uses the more portable `printf`, which makes it clearer what is output.

---

Update:

Simplified version with `for ((...;...;...))` loops in lieu of `while`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Please input a number for a magical surprise diagram: " input

for (( tri1 = 1; tri1 <= input; tri1++ )); do
  for (( tri2 = 1; tri2 <= tri1; tri2++ )); do
    printf '*'
  done
  printf '\n'
done
```

Even further simplification, replacing the inner loop with a `printf` trick (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/45375)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Please input a number for a magical surprise diagram: " input

for (( i = 1; i <= input; i++ )); do
  printf '*%.s' $(seq $i)
  printf '\n'
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt know you could do this, and ill try to implement it!

Comment: @user3317098: You're welcome; I should also have mentioned `for ((...;...;...))` loops, which are better suited to your task - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using quotes

```
while [ "$tri1" -le "$input" ]; do
  while [ "$tri2" -le " $tri1" ]; do ...
```

should fix it.  Proably you have spaces on $input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but now it says that there is a  line 8: [: : integer expression expected

Answer (score 0):

See the difference. This works

```
echo $(( 1+1 ))
```

while this one does not

```
echo $( ( 1+1 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed it and added quotes, but I am still getting line 8: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: Once i've corrected this mistake, I stopped getting this error.

Comment: Another victim of [the Indian space](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645).

Answer (score 0):

The two starting parentheses `((` must be a single token for an arithmetic expression, so that it cannot be confused with two nested subshells `( ...; ( ... ))`.

Between `((` and `))` you can have any amount of whitespace around the operands and operators of the expression.

The first expression in your code should read either

```
tri2=$(( tri2 + 1 ))  # POSIX
```

or

```
(( tri2=tri2 + 1 ))   # Valid in Bash and ksh93
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a faster and more readable way to print ranging multiples of a character or string.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please input a number for a magical surprise diagram : " input

for i in $(seq $input); do
    c+="*"
    echo "$c"
done
```

It's important to use quotes here as `*` will otherwise expand to file names in the current directory.