# Unary operator expected in Bash

Tags: bash, integer, operator-keyword

I've seen questions regarding the same issue, but all of them are about strings. How about integers? Why am I getting the "unary operator expected" error?

```
 if [ $(date +%k%M) -ge ${!BLOCK1FRAN} ] ; then whatever ; fi
```

Comment: You are using indirection. If the variable `${BLOCK1FRAN}` points to an empty variable, you'll get the error message.

Comment: The canonical may be *["unary operator expected" error in Bash if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using indirection. If the variable `${BLOCK1FRAN}` points to an empty variable, you'll get the error message. Make sure that the variable pointed by `${BLOCK1FRAN}` contains a valid numeric value.

If you want an empty string and nonnumeric values to be evaluated as zero (`0`), use the following syntax.

```
if [[ $(date +%k%M) -ge ${!BLOCK1FRAN} ]]; then whatever ; fi
```

Comment: +1 Another approach: Declare names in bash you expect to be numeric to have the integer attribute. This gives a semblance of indirection, but also guarantees the value will be numeric. `declare -i x BLOCK1FRAN; BLOCK1FRAN=x; echo $BLOCK1FRAN`

Comment: Double brackets instead of singles ones seem to work well, thank you. May I ask why this is? And why would anyone choose to use [ instad of [[?

Comment: The main difference between `[ and ]` and `[[ and ]]` is that word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the latter. For example, if you have `*` within `[ and ]`, it will be expanded to the files in the `$PWD` whereas the same `*` inside `[[ and ]]` won't. And most likely you intend to use the literal `*`. For more details see `bash` manpage.

Answer (score -1):

It looks good to me. Are you sure you've set BLOCK1FRAN correctly?

```
whatever() { echo "it works"; }
foo=42
BLOCK1FRAN=foo
if [ $(date +%k%M) -ge ${!BLOCK1FRAN} ] ; then whatever ; fi

it works
```