# [: -gt: unary operator expected

Tags: bash

I don't write a lot of Bash, so I'm a bit stumped as to how to fix this. I need to check whether a value returned from a command is greater than `x`. When it runs though I get `[: -gt: unary operator expected` which I'm unable to fix.

Here is my script,

```
#!/bin/sh
ERROR=0
PHPCPDLevel=100

# PHPCPD
echo "PHP CopyPaste Detection (Limit is at least ${PHPCPDLevel}%"
PHPCPD="phpcpd ."
if [[ `echo $PHPCPD | grep "%" | cut -d'.' -f1` -gt "$PHPCPDLevel" ]]
  then
    echo $PHPCPD
    ERROR=1
  else
    echo "... -> Only `echo $PHPCPD | grep "%" | cut -d'.' -f1`%"
fi

echo "Finished!"
exit $ERROR
```

**Update:**
I think I've done it:

```
#!/bin/sh
ERROR=0
PHPCPDLevel=25

# PHPCPD
echo "PHP CopyPaste Detection (Limit is at most ${PHPCPDLevel}%)"
PHPCPD="phpcpd ."
PERCENTAGE=$($PHPCPD | grep "%" | cut -d'.' -f1)
if [ ${PERCENTAGE} -gt ${PHPCPDLevel} ]
  then
    echo $PHPCPD
    ERROR=1
  else
    echo "Only $PERCENTAGE%"
fi

exit $ERROR
```

Comment: What is output of `echo $PHPCPD | grep "%" | cut -d'.' -f1`

Comment: It is good to perform any operation first and store result in variable then compare.

Comment: Are you sure there is no space before or after 5?

Comment: I don't think there is a space, when I run it, it seems fine.

Comment: ok change shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: `echo $PHPCPD` is not like you run command? Try with `PHPCPD=$( phpcpd . | grep "%" | cut -d'.' -f1)` and compare it like `if [ $PHPCPD  -gt "$PHPCPDLevel" ]`

Comment: Ok, but quote the variables in the expansion, like `if [ "$PERCENTAGE" -gt "$PHPCPDLevel" ]` otherwise the it will fail if the pipeline does not give any output.

Comment: This is weird, my edited script works on my Mac, but when it's running on GitLab it's telling me that 9% is > 99% (I've since changed the level).

Comment: Are you comparing with the percentage mark `%` inside the variables?

Comment: Nope. https://gist.github.com/jbrooksuk/b36403f6277a94bc4faa

Comment: And https://gist.github.com/jbrooksuk/b36403f6277a94bc4faa#comment-1269875 is the output from GitLab-CI.

Comment: The canonical may be *["unary operator expected" error in Bash if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that `[` is a command. It maybe built into your shell, but it's still a command. It is expecting a particular set of parameters, and will give you an error when it gets something it doesn't understand. In fact, you can replace `[ ... ]` with `test ...` if that makes things a bit easier to understand:

For example:

```
test -gt 34
```

Will return:

```
bash: test: -gt: unary operator expected
```

Hmmm... same error message.

When you get things like this, you should use `set -xv` and `set +xv` around the problem area of your shell script. The `set -xv` will print out the shell command to be executed, and then will show you what the command line looked like after it has been <strike>mangled</strike> I mean *interpolated* by the shell.

I suspect that your error is:

```
if [ ${PERCENTAGE} -gt ${PHPCPDLevel} ]
```

That `${PERCENTAGE}` is a blank value. If you use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` you won't get that error. The `[[ ... ]]` is parsed a bit differently than `[ ... ]` because it's a compound command. The shell interpolations are done after the initial command is parsed, so it's a bit more forgiving if you miss a quotation mark or strings contain unexpected characters.

So:

```
ERROR=0
PHPCPDLevel=25

# PHPCPD
echo "PHP CopyPaste Detection (Limit is at most ${PHPCPDLevel}%)"
export PS4="\$LINENO: "     # Prints out the line number being executed by debug
set -xv                     # Turn on debugging
PHPCPD="phpcpd ."
PERCENTAGE=$($PHPCPD | grep "%" | cut -d'.' -f1)
if [[ ${PERCENTAGE} -gt ${PHPCPDLevel} ]]  # Use [[ ... ]] instead of [ .. ]
then
    echo $PHPCPD
    ERROR=1
else
    echo "Only $PERCENTAGE%"
fi
set +xv                     # Turn off debugging

exit $ERROR
```

Now, you'll see what the various commands that set environment variables are returning, and possibly see something you didn't quite expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use double brackets `[[ ... ]]` in `sh`. Change your sheebang to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or change the syntax to use single brackets `[ ... ]`. Don't forget to quote the terms inside the expression if you do that.

Comment: I've changed it, but it's still not worked. I'm just trying something slightly different now.

Comment: @James Also you do `PHPCPD="phpcpd ."` and then execute `echo $PHPCPD`. Don't you wan't to run the command, like " `phpcpd . | grep ...`?

Comment: @user000001 yes, that was my plan.

Comment: Ok, I switched to `#!/bin/bash` and using double brackets to compare `[[ 9 -le 5 ]]` but that's returning true. What?

Comment: @James Are you sure? Try `[[ 9 -le 5 ]] && echo true || echo false` on a terminal. I get false.

Comment: Yep, absolutely sure.