# Bash - 'unary operator expected'

Tags: bash, sh, bc

I have a shell script which has over 200,000 iterations. Here is the piece of code which is giving me problems:

```
if [ 1 -eq `echo "$sums>$maxs" | bc` ] ;
then
    hmax=$h;
    kmax=$k;
    maxs=$sums;
fi
```

sums, maxs, h, and k are defined earlier. I am looping through different values of h and k and sums is calculated from them. But, only for specific values of h and k, I get this error:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./zhu-kanamori.sh: line 173: [: 1: unary operator expected
```

I don't understand why. I saw some similar questions, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer. What might be the solution? I am clear on how to compare two floats. Why do I get this error only in some cases?

Comment: Please reduce your question to something more concise, it will help us help you.

Comment: Okay, but I just added the whole code for context. The actual question is just in the beginning. I am gonna change it now.

Comment: `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` is an error emitted by `bc`.  Clearly, `$sums` and `$maxs` are not what you think they are.  (ie, they are not simple numbers)

Comment: They are actually floats. Should I add some more of the code here? Because I don't understand that if there is a syntax error, why is there not an error for most of the iterations?

Comment: Well, awk is an option, but can't bc be used at all? Just asking.

Comment: Running `bc` over 2,000,000 times just to compare two floats is grossly inefficient. Consider writing your script in a language that can handle floating-point arithmetic natively.

Comment: I actually am doing this in matlab. But this was kind of an experiment

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x yourscript`, and reproduce the bug in that mode. You'll see the **actual** echo, with values substituted. I'd be very surprised if that didn't make the bug obvious (or, at least, the behavior wherein `bc` doesn't emit any output reproducible).

Comment: The canonical may be *["unary operator expected" error in Bash if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two errors are directly linked:

- `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` means that `bc` didn't understand the string it was passed. This means that `$sums` and `$maxs` weren't actually the floating-point values you think they were; run with `bash -x yourscript` to see the actual values in use (and thereby to be able to amend your question to include actual values that make your error reproducible).
- `./zhu-kanamori.sh: line 173: [: 1: unary operator expected` means that `[` expects `-eq` to have two operands, but it was only passed one. This happened because you didn't adequately quote the command substitution, so an empty string emitted by `bc` when it failed was treated as zero arguments to `test`, as opposed to a single empty argument.

Comment: Okay thanks. It seems some $sums values are coming out undefined