# Getting "line 11: [: 9: unary operator expected"

Tags: arrays, bash, bubble-sort

I was writing this simple Bubble Sort code in Bash and I faced this strange error. Although I am getting the correct output, this error keeps bugging me.

**Output**

```
Enter the array elements: 9 4 1 2 3 0 4 5
Array elements: 
9  4  1  2  3  0  4  5  
bubble.bash: line 11: [: 9: unary operator expected
Sorted Array elements: 
0  1  2  3  4  4  5  9
```

**The Code**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the array elements: " -a arr
echo "Array elements: "
for elem in ${arr[@]}
do 
    echo -ne "$elem  "
done
echo
for (( i = 0; i <= ${#arr[@]}-1; i++ )); do
    for (( j = 0; j <= ${#arr[@]}-$i-1; j++ )); do
        if [ ${arr[j]} -gt ${arr[j+1]} ]; then
            t=${arr[$j]}
            arr[$j]=${arr[$j+1]}
            arr[$j+1]=$t
        fi
    done 
done
echo "Sorted Array elements: "
for elem in ${arr[@]}
do 
    echo -ne "$elem  "
done
echo
```

Comment: Let's say arr has 3 elements. When i is 0, j can reach 3-0-1=2. And when j is 2, arr[j+1], i.e arr[3], is empty. Hence the error you're seeing.

Comment: use if [[ ${arr[j]} -gt ${arr[j+1]} ]] or use double quote on variable. this link could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/unary-operator-expected-error-in-bash-if-condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["unary operator expected" error in Bash if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617843/unary-operator-expected-error-in-bash-if-condition)

Comment: Run your script through https://shellcheck.net and implement its suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line
`for (( i = 0; i <= ${#arr[@]}-1; i++ ));`

to:
`for (( i = 0; i < ${#arr[@]}-1; i++ ));`

and
`for (( j = 0; j <= ${#arr[@]}-$i-1; j++ ))`

to:
`for (( j = 0; j < ${#arr[@]}-$i-1; j++ ))`