# Bash conditional on command exit code

Tags: bash

In bash, I want to say "if a file doesn't contain XYZ, then" do a bunch of things.  The most natural way to transpose this into code is something like:

```
if [ ! grep --quiet XYZ "$MyFile" ] ; then
   ... do things ...
fi
```

But of course, that's not valid Bash syntax.  I could use backticks, but then I'll be testing the output of the file.  The two alternatives I can think of are:

```
grep --quiet XYZ "$MyFile"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   ... do things ...
fi
```

And

```
grep --quiet XYZ "$MyFile" ||
   (  ... do things ...
   )
```

I kind of prefer the second one, it's more Lispy and the || for control flow isn't that uncommon in scripting languages.  I can see arguments for the first one too, although when the person reads the first line, they don't know *why* you're executing grep, it looks like you're executing it for it's main effect, rather than just to control a branch in script.

Is there a third, more direct way which uses an `if` statement and has the `grep` in the condition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [encounter "unary operator expected" in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586213/encounter-unary-operator-expected-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
if grep --quiet .....
then
    # If grep finds something
fi
```

or if the grep fails

```
if ! grep --quiet .....
then
    # If grep doesn't find something
fi
```

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks.  In my defense, I haven't seen that in any tutorials, even ones that talk about checking the exit code of a command.

Comment: `[` is kind of an alias for `test` (which also requires `]`). So `if [ ... ]` is equivalent to `if test ...`

Comment: What if you want to test multiple conditions, one of which is exit status of a command? As in:

    `if [[ $OS == "windows" && command-exit-status==0 ]]; ...`

? I can run the command first and save `$?` of course, but I'd like the shortcut `&&` behavior so it doesn't run the command unless `$OS==windows`. Any good ideas?

Comment: @GaryO: You could write it like `if [[ $OS == "windows" ]] && command; then` or if even without the `if` like `[[ $OS == "windows" ]] && command && echo "All ok"`

Answer (score 14):

You don't need the `[` `]` (`test`) to check the return value of a command. Just try:

```
if ! grep --quiet XYZ "$MyFile" ; then
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of taste since there obviously are multiple working solutions. When I deal with a problem like this, I usually apply `wc -l` after grep in order to count the lines that match. Then you have a single integer number that you can evaluate within a test condition. If the question only is whether there is a match at all (the number of matching lines does  not matter), then applying `wc` probably is OTT and evaluation of `grep`'s return code seems to be the best solution:

> Normally, the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1
>   otherwise. But the exit status is 2 if an error occurred, unless the
>   -q or --quiet or --silent option is used and a selected line is found. Note, however, that POSIX only mandates, for programs such as grep,
>   cmp, and diff, that the exit status in case of error be greater than
>   1; it is therefore advisable, for the sake of portability, to use
>   logic that tests for this general condition instead of strict equality
>   with 2.