# How to use grep with single brackets?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I was looking at [an answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/669486/1602022) about which bracket pair to use with `if` in a bash script. `[[` is less surprising and has more features such as pattern matching (`=~`) whereas `[` and `test` are built-in and POSIX compliant making them portable.

Recently, I was attempting to test the result of a `grep` command and it was failing with `[: too many arguments`. I was using `[`. But, when I switched to `[[` it worked. How would I do such a test with `[` in order to maintain the portability?

This is the test that failed:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > slew_pattern << EOF
g -x"$
EOF


if [ $(grep -E -f slew_pattern /etc/sysconfig/ntpd) ]; then
        echo "slew mode"

else
        echo "not slew mode"

fi
```

And the test that succeeded:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > slew_pattern << EOF
g -x"$
EOF

if [[ $(grep -E -f slew_pattern /etc/sysconfig/ntpd) ]]; then
        echo "slew mode"

else
        echo "not slew mode"

fi
```

Comment: Related, but not really a good duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586213/encounter-unary-operator-expected-in-bash-script

Comment: If you are looking to set `ntp` in `slew mode` to compensate for the leapsecond before 6/30 and restore the original config on 7/1, take a look at [**Fix leapsecond 2015 set ntp slew mode**](http://pastebin.com/7cqTT5KD) **Note:** the restart command is distribution dependent, so you may need to modify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [ $(grep -E -f slew_pattern /etc/sysconfig/ntpd) ]; then
```

This command will certainly fail for multiple matches. It will throw an error as the `grep` output is being split on line ending.

Multiple matches of `grep` are separated by new line and the test command becomes like:

```
[ match1 match2 match3 ... ]
```

which doesn't make much of a sense. You will get different error messages as the number of matches returned by `grep` (i.e the number of arguments for test command `[`).

For example:

2 matches will give you `unary operator expected` error

3 matches will give you `binary operator expected` error and

more than 3 matches  will give you `too many arguments` error or such, in Bash.

---

You need to quote variables inside `[` to prevent word splitting.

On the other hand, the Bash specific `[[` prevents word splitting by default. Thus the `grep` output doesn't get split on new line and remains a single string which is a valid argument for the test command.

So the solution is to look only at the exit status of `grep`:

```
if  grep -E -f slew_pattern /etc/sysconfig/ntpd; then
```

Or use quote when capturing output:

```
if [ "$(grep -E -f slew_pattern /etc/sysconfig/ntpd)" ]; then
```

Note:

1. You don't really need to capture the output here, simply looking at the exit status will suffice.
2. Additionally, you can suppress output of `grep` command to be printed with `-q` option and errors with `-s` option.

Comment: I would upvote if your first recommendation would be simply `if grep -q -E -f ...`